# How to add variables that are passed on through the URL to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
<?php
$i = $_GET['i'];
echo $i;
$values = array();

while ($i > 0)
{

$expense = $_GET['expense_' + i];
$amount = $_GET['amount_' + i];

$values[$expense] = $amount;
i--;

print_r($values);

}
?>
```

i represents the number of sets of variables I have that have been passed through from the previous page. What I'm trying to do is add the expenses to the amounts and put them in an array as (lets just say for this example there were 3 expenses and 3 amounts) [expense_3 => amount_3, expense_2 => amount_2, expense_1 => amount_1]. The names of the variables are successfully passed through via the url as amount_1=50, amount_2=50, expense_1=food, expense2=gas, etc... as well as $i, I just dont know how to add those variables to an array each time.
Right now with this code I'm getting

4
Array ( [] => ) Array ( [] => ) Array ( [] => ) Array ( [] => )

I apologize if I'm not being clear enough, but I am pretty inexperienced with PHP.

Comment: You should add '$' sign before 'i'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error you're getting is because you're using `i` instead of `$i` - however - that can be resolved easily.

What you're looking to do is "simple" and can be accomplished with string-concatenation. It looks like you're attempting this with `$_GET['expense'] + i`, but not quite correct.

To properly build the parameter name, you'll want something like `$_GET['expense_' . $i]`, here you can see to concatenate strings you use the `.` operator - not the `+` one.

I'm going to switch your logic to use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop for my example:

```
$values = array();
for ($i = $_GET['i']; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $expense = $_GET['expense_' . $i];
    $amount = $_GET['amount_' . $i];

    $values[$expense] = $amount;
}

print_r($values);
```

This is following your original logic, but it will effectively reverse the variables (counting from `$i` down to `1`). If you want to count up, you can change your for loop to:

```
$numVariables = $_GET['i'];
for ($index = 1; $index <= $numVariables; $index++) {
    $expense = $_GET['expense_' . $index];
    ...
```

Comment: This completely fixes what I was attempting to do. Looks like I have a lot of learning to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Or just [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array and pass it to the next site, where you [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the array
would be much easier ;)

Comment: The values are never in an array in the first page, they are user inputed values to where the user can make as many fields as they'd like, and it names each field and passes it to the next one. why would putting it into an array on the first page and then passing the array over be easier then passing the values over and then creating an array that way? Also, I don't quite understand what serializing is :P

Comment: oh sry, I thought the variables in the url are from an array